# PostgreSql function (that returns table) in relation

Tags: postgresql, function, join

I have server UDF **rm_all(tnIdRM)** that returns table with exactly one row, or no rows if there is no items for given parameter value .  I call this function many times - it gather some related data from 4 tables.
Now I need to relate result from this function with "master" table named `zapugo`.  In table `zapugo` there is column `zapugo.zapu_rm` I could use as parameter when I call mentioned function rm_all().
But, I didn't find a way to relate table zapugo with resulting table from function rm_all().
It will be simplest if I could write statement:

```
with rmall as (
   select * from rm_all(zapugo.zapu_rm)
   )
select zapugo.*, rmall.*
   from zapugo
   where <condition to filter zapugo table>
```

But Postgres raises error:
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "zapugo"
(and points to "from rm_all(zapugo.zapu_rm)")

Very similar error message raises when I try other ways to achieve same goal.
My answer is:
How to write SQL to relate table `zapugo` with results of function with parameter?  Parameter will be accept from column `zapugo.zapu_rm`.

Comment: `from zapugo, rm_all(zapugo.zapu_rm)` maybe?

Comment: Are you maybe talking about an inner join clause? https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-inner-join/

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name is exactly correct. You can't refer to a relation from your FROM clause in the CTE. You have to call the function in the SELECT.

Comment: I reassess my earlier attempts and find that query ```select * from zapugo, rm_all(zapugo.zapu_rm)``` really works.  I am sure that I have tried such form, but maybe I made some other mistake in that attempt.  Moreover, I found that I can give an alias to function result, and so optimize query result: ```select zapugo.zapu_id, rmall.rm_name from zapugo, rm_all(zapugo.zapu_rm) as rmall;```.  Thank you, @a_horse_with_no_name, how I could mark your answer as "question is solved"?

Comment: @Otávio Monteagudo - Today is a miracle day, it seems to be!  Now every try give result with no error.  I don't know where I did mistakes in past three days - I have tried join and other ways also, but with no success.  Now everything works!  Thank you, too.